# How to skip before_create callback in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, callback

Hi i am using a Rails application with ruby-2.2.5 and rails 5 i am using rspec to test my controller. there is a callback in User model `before_create :create_token` i want to skip this callback in rspec.

```
spec/controllers/check_token_controller_spec.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

describe CheckTokenController do
  before do
    @user = User.create!(fullname: 'saddam husain',
                         email: 'saddam@gmail.com',
                         password: 'pass',
                         password_confirmation: 'pass',token: 'xyz')
  end

  describe 'POST create' do 
    subject { post :create, params: params }

    context 'when credentials are valid' do
      let(:params) do
        { data: { attributes: { username: 'saddam@gmail.com', token: 'xyz' } } }
      end

      it { is_expected.to have_http_status(200) }
    end

    context 'when credentials are invalid' do
      let(:params) do
        { data: { attributes: { username: 'saddam@gmail.com', token: '' } } }
      end

      it { is_expected.to have_http_status(401) }
    end
  end
end
```

i want to skip create_token callback. please help me how to skip.

Comment: Question should be "why do you want to do that?"

Answer (score 5):

A quick solution is using the [RSpec#allow_any_instance_of](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.7/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods.html#allow_any_instance_of-instance_method) method to stub the `create_token` for all classes.

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:create_token)
  @user = User.create!(fullname: 'saddam husain', email: 'saddam@gmail.com', ...)
end
```

This isn't recommended ([reference](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.7/rspec-mocks/#label-Settings+mocks+or+stubs+on+any+instance+of+a+class); please read the full section), and you probably need to skip a third-party code, or service integration inside `create_token` method. So you should mock this service instead of the `create_token` method. Here is a sample on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19281316/1042324.

Let us know the content of your `create_token` method so we can help you better.